# Need to know order in which the constructors are called in the program

Tags: java, constructor

I need to know the order, in which the constructors will be called.

Point class:

```
public class Point
{
    public int x = 0;
    public int y = 0;

    // a constructor!
    public Point(int a, int b) {
        x = a;
        y = b;
    }
}
```

Rectangle class:

```
public class Rectangle
{
    public int width = 0;
    public int height = 0;
    public Point origin;

    // four constructors
    public Rectangle() {
        origin = new Point(0, 0);
    }
    public Rectangle(Point p) {
        origin = p;
    }
    public Rectangle(int w, int h) {
        origin = new Point(0, 0);
        width = w;
        height = h;
    }
    public Rectangle(Point p, int w, int h) {
       origin = p;
       width = w;
       height = h;
    }

    // a method for moving the rectangle
    public void move(int x, int y) {
        origin.x = x;
        origin.y = y;
    }

    // a method for computing the area of the rectangle
    public int getArea() {
        return width * height;
    }
}
```

A class which creates objects:

```
public class CreateObjectDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Declare and create a point object
        //and two rectangle objects.
        Point originOne = new Point(23, 94);
        Rectangle rectOne = new Rectangle(originOne, 100, 200);
        Rectangle rectTwo = new Rectangle(50, 100);
        System.out.println("Width of rectOne: " +  rectOne.width);
        System.out.println("Height of rectOne: " + rectOne.height);
        System.out.println("Area of rectOne: " + rectOne.getArea());

        rectTwo.origin = originOne;
    }
}
```

1. In which order are the constructors in class Rectangle called?
2. When will the `public Rectangle(Point p)` be called?
3. What does the statement `rectTwo.origin = originOne` do ?

The program is from Oracle's Java Tutorial site.

Comment: Regardless if it's homework or not, don't cheat yourself out of a learning experience. Amith, please tell us your answers and explanations for them first.

Comment: Are you sure this is officially from an Oracle site? There's a few things wrong (or at least bad practice) with this code, I'd be surprised if they condoned it...

Comment: the code pretty much has all the answers. -1

Comment: @emboss please refer to the site http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objects.html you can view the code

Comment: @emboss what is the bad practice in the code?

Comment: @Amith: public member variables, the constructors duplicate code instead of delegating via this(...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the control flow is in program order (i.e. left-to-right), with the following exceptions:

- Parameters to methods and constructors are evaluated before the method/constructors itself
- The program starts with the main method.

Thus we have the following order:

1. `Point originOne = new Point(23, 94);` - this will call the `Point` constructor.
2. `Rectangle rectOne = new Rectangle(originOne, 100, 200);` - this will call the `Rectangle` constructor with a Point and two `int` arguments.
3. `Rectangle rectTwo = new Rectangle(50, 100);` - this will call the `Rectangle` constructor with two `int` arguments.

   1. This constructor, in turn, will in `origin = new Point(0, 0);` call the `Point` constructor.

There are no more explicit constructor calls. But each of these calls includes an implicit call to the constructor of its superclass (which is `Object` here) at the start.

The constructor `Rectangle(Point)` is not called at all, it seems.

`rectTwo.origin = originOne;` changes the origin of the second rectangle from (0,0) to the same point which is used by `rectOne`, e.g. (23,94).

Comment: one more doubt what is the purpose of public Rectangle() in the code ?

Comment: It is not used here - it allows creating an rectangle with zero size and on zero origin. You may want to use this to create a template object which you give to other code for filling in the values. (But I would say the whole design here is flawed - normally you don't want public fields, and even less with mutable values like a Point here.)

Answer (score 2):

1. All the constructors called in this program are done so in this order:

   ```
   Point(int x, int y)
   Rectangle(Point p, int w, int h)
   Rectangle(int w, int h)
   Point(int x, int y) // (called by Rectangle)
   ```
2. It isn't called anywhere, so far.
3. This makes `rectTwo`'s "origin" equal to the the origin represented by `originOne`

Answer (score 2):

1. Constructor calls:
   Point(int, int)
   Rectangle(Point, int, int)
   Rectangle(int, int)
   Point(int, int)
2. Rectangle(Point) is never called.
3. That statement is setting the origin of `rectTwo` to `originOne`.

Answer (score 1):

1.) Only one constructor get called for each of the 2 instantiation. Order based on the `main` method:

```
public Rectangle(Point p, int w, int h)
public Rectangle(int w, int h)
```

2.) Never.

3.) Change the `origin` field of `rectTwo` object to `originOne`, so that the `Point` `rectTwo.origin` is now (23,94) instead of (0.0).